# No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found due to CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj in Debug for a Release build

Tags: windows, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I've got a strange problem that recently appeared (that worked last week and I can't understand what changed)

As usual I run cmake with the following command line in order to configure a Release build for some c or c++ libraries with Visual Studio 2019 tools on Windows :

```
cmake "./Sources" -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="./Build" -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-DNDEBUG -MT -Ob2 -O2 -FS"
```

But since a few days I receive this error for each Release build I try :

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.18363.
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (PROJECT):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Further investigations shows that the problem comes from the tool used by cmake to check the compiler, somehow it seems that it doesn't care about the -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release argument, and tries to compile this as a Debug version. I found this in CMakeError.log :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /nologo /W0 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:queue CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp

Build FAILED.

"C:\cpplibs\Intermediate\JsonCpp\1.9.3\Windows\x64\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.20032601-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/MDd' with '/MT' [C:\cpplibs\Intermediate\JsonCpp\1.9.3\Windows\x64\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.20032601-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]
  cl : command line warning D9025: overriding '/Od' with '/O2' [C:\cpplibs\Intermediate\JsonCpp\1.9.3\Windows\x64\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.20032601-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]"C:\cpplibs\Intermediate\JsonCpp\1.9.3\Windows\x64\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.20032601-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  cl : command line error D8016: '/RTC1' and '/O2' command-line options are incompatible [C:\cpplibs\Intermediate\JsonCpp\1.9.3\Windows\x64\Release\CMakeFiles\3.17.20032601-MSVC_2\CompilerIdCXX\CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj]
```

I also opened the generated CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj and it contains only a Debug configuration whereas I asked for a Release build ! So this explains why several compiler options are overrided and, in particular, why /RTC1 is present and declared incompatible with expected release options like /O2 ...

I also tried on my collegue computer, and for other libraries in pure "c" language where it generate a CompilerIdC.vcxproj project, the result is the same since a few days wheras it worked like a charm before.

Does anyone have an idea on how to get cmake back to normal behavior for configuring release builds ?

Comment: You say this used to work but now doesn't.  What version of CMake are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it,

In fact during the configuration step using this command :

```
cmake "./Sources" -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="./Build" -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-DNDEBUG -MT -Ob2 -O2 -FS"
```

A lot of cl commands are run, but these are just for testing the platform capabilities. They contain a lot of hard coded Debug flags even if we ask for a final release build. They don't compile things that are used in the final program, they just allow to test if some features are available on the current environment. Overriding some flags at this step is not what I wanted actually, It's just useful at the next step.

If I run the command without flag override (in *CL* env var) I can run this cmake line without issue anymore.

Solved !

Answer (score 0):

This portion of your CMake command line look suspicious:

```
-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-DNDEBUG -MT -Ob2 -O2 -FS"
```

These compile options appear to be more GCC-style, rather than the compile options that the Visual Studio compiler accepts (which begin with a `/`). Consider removing this, or revising it to apply the *appropriate* compile options for the Visual Studio compiler. In doing so, you should avoid manually manipulating the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` variable, because this is a **discouraged** practice. Instead, try using the [`add_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/command/add_compile_options.html) command in the top-level CMakeLists.txt file.

Furthermore, the errors you receive seem to indicate that one or more of the following occurred:

- Your Visual Studio C compiler was updated, or not installed correctly. Check that it is still *properly* installed, and consider *re-installing* it.
- Your build configurations somehow got confused and mixed-up. It is always a good idea, especially when having these kind of errors, to clear the CMake cache and/or completely delete the CMake build folder, and start fresh. There may be some stale or ill-configured variables in your CMake cache, and re-running CMake from scratch will resolve these issues.

Comment: the - or / are usually interpreted the same way, this don't cause any issue here, but I agree, it could in other specific cases.